# I can not deploy my shiny application on the server

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I tried to deploy my Shiny application on ShinyApp.io

I followed the classic procedure

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='my-name',
                          token='XXXXXXXXX........',
                          secret='XXXXXX....................')
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp("myshinyAppPath/myshinyAppPath/....")
```

but I have some problems with probably the package`shinydashboard`

Here is below the warning message

```
Warning messages:
1: In fileDependencies.R(file) :
  Failed to parse C:/Users/ACER/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpYjboca/file539453624443/app.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.
2: In fileDependencies.R(file) :
  Failed to parse C:/Users/ACER/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpYjboca/file539453624443/listeHop.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.
3: Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'raw'
 (Using default: en_US)
```

And what is displayed on the browser:

[image]

I can't figure out the problem

Comment: Yes I have package installed. And to be sure I reinstalled it. My application run well locally, even though I think a part of the package seems to be installed in the Local Temp file

Comment: Make sure that you have `library(shinydashboard)` at the top in `ui.R`

Comment: I am using a unique ```app.R``` file and the top I have ```library (shiny)``` and then ``  `library(shinydashboard)``` as the first two scripts

Comment: Then I am not sure.  It should work.  Hard to diagnose without looking at the code.

Comment: Can the problem be due to the binary file of shinydashboard installed in the folder: Local/Temp....

Comment: Should I share my codes? It’s pretty long script.

Comment: It may be best to post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does your app reference any local files on your machine?  In particular, what is the value of `file` in your call to `read.table` in the third warning message?